Magento 2 : How To Find Magento Tax Setting
How to find the order is inclusive of tax or exclusive of tax through REST API?

Which API you are use to get the order information?

/rest/V1/orders REST API

I post answer, please check, if that help upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community as well.

You need to check the API response and do code like this :
If (base_subtotal == base_subtotal_incl_tax)
     "ORDER IS INCLUDING TAX";
else
     "ORDER IS EXCLUDING TAX";


Both inclusive and exclusive of orders, remains the same value.
Is there any trick to find order's tax inclusive or exclusive?
